# Problems exporting graphs with descriptions to raster image files

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, labeling

I'm generating graphs with descriptions for upload to a website that only accepts raster image files. I can produce what I'm looking for in Mathematica 12.0's font-end using either `Labeled` or `Column`, but when I export the results as high-resolution raster images, a lot of white space is included around the descriptions.

Here are some examples:

`Labeled`

```
Framed@Labeled[
  Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger], 
   PlotLabel -> "Descriptive Plot Title", 
   PlotLegends -> {"First Function Description", 
     "Second Function Description"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Verical Axis Label"}],
  "label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label"]
```

produces this in the front-end:

[image]

But

```
Export["test_lbl.png", %, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

generates this instead:

[image]

Similarly, `Column`

```
Column[{Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Large, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger], 
   PlotLabel -> "Descriptive Plot Title", 
   PlotLegends -> {"First Function Description", 
     "Second Function Description"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Verical Axis Label"}],
  "label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label label label label label label label label label 
label label label"}, Frame -> All]
```

produces this in the front end:

[image]

but

```
Export["test_col.png", %, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

generates this instead:

[image]

Exporting as PDFs gives what I'm looking for, and of course, I can crop the PNGs, but I prefer not having to do any post-processing after exporting. So, can anyone tell me how to get `Export` to reproduce what I'm seeing in the front-end?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mathematica 12.2, your first example exported without any problem even on higher than 300 but on your second example, the problem shows up not in the vertical direction but in horizontal!

#### First example

ImageResolution : 300
[image]

#### Second example

with or without specifying `ImageResolution`:

[image]

It seems that it somehow conflicts with `"label label ..."`. If you apply `Text` to "label label ...", the problem disappears:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'll check out `Text` and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently running version 12.1, and with or without `Text`, everything exports just fine! So, this seems to be a moot problem for now. And I've been post-processing all this time, anyway, to cap the filesize. (Perhaps I should investigate doing that directly from Mathematica...)

Nonetheless, since this is the only answer this question has received since I posted it ten months ago, I'll go ahead and award it the win. Thanks!